# Are NSUndomanager changes persisted between launches with CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, nsundomanager, state-restoration

I'm implementing undos in an app using CoreData. My app also uses State Restoration.

What's not clear to me from the docs is if the NSUndoManager will persist its undo history between launches / state restoration? It's not a major issue if it doesn't, it's just I need to know so I can code for it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not. It also does not support `NSCoding` or `NSSecureCoding`, so there appears to be no way to archive it yourself.